# How to show a list of all my todos across all the files of my project?

Tags: emacs

I am an Emacs newbie transitioning from Neovim.
I want something that will show me a list of all of my todos across all the files of the project.
I've tried the following packages:

1. [hl-todo](https://github.com/tarsius/hl-todo)
2. [fixmee](https://github.com/rolandwalker/fixmee)

Both of them can highlight todos, and show a list of all the todos in the current buffer.
But, what I need is a list of todos across all the files of the project and not just the current buffer. They do provide such functionality, but it is very clunky and impossible to bind to just a single key (they require choosing a path where to search and pressing enter).

The question: how can I show a list of all my todos across all the files in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about todo modes, but using the `rg` (ripgrep) package, it is easy to add custom commands.  For example, to define a command that searches for 'TODO' or 'FIXME' in the current project,

```
(rg-define-search my-rg-todo
  :query "(TODO|FIXME)"
  :format regexp
  :dir project
  :files current)
```

There are a lot of other similar solutions, like builtin `rgrep`, `ag` or another ripgrep/ag library.

Comment: Yeap, this is it. It works just as I like it. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: A followup question, please. Your suggestion opens a new buffer called *rg*. It has the results highlighted and all, but not clickable. How can I make them clickable?

Comment: @RefaelSheinker when I run that they are clickable - I can click on the `<line>:<column>` to display the match, and cycle through them with `next-error`